# Convert preconfigured timestamp in metabase from utc format to ist using sql queries

Tags: mysql, postgresql, metabase

[showing the initial timestamp format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxUTZ.png)

Currently I am working on metabase. I have my timestamp something like this   'Friday, June 23, 2017 8:43 AM'. I need to convert this timestamp from utc to ist form.

The code is something like this

---

```
SELECT CAST("public"."locations"."timestamp" AS date) AS "timestamp"
FROM "public"."locations"
GROUP BY CAST("public"."locations"."timestamp" AS date)
ORDER BY CAST("public"."locations"."timestamp" AS date) ASC
```

Comment: What's your actual *question*?

Comment: i have to convert this format to ist (currently it is showing according to utc ) using mysql queries

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL<sup>1</sup> and assuming a simplified scenario to concentrate on converting your timestamps to `IST` such is this one:

```
CREATE TABLE locations
(
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    your_timestamp timestamp with time zone
) ;
```

NOTE: don't use `timestamp` as a column name, to avoid confusions. `timestamp` is already a `type`.

```
INSERT INTO locations
    (your_timestamp)
VALUES
    ('2017-01-01 10:00:00 UTC'),
    ('2017-01-01 10:00:00 Europe/Rome'),
    ('2017-01-01 10:00:00 America/New_York'),
    ('2017-01-01 10:00:00 IST') ;
```

You'd convert all those times (not only the ones already entered as UTC, or with the local time zone of the client connecting to the database), you would use:

```
SELECT
    id, 
    your_timestamp,
    your_timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS timestamp_utc,
    your_timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'IST' AS timestamp_ist
FROM
    locations ;
```

```
id | your_timestamp         | timestamp_utc       | timestamp_ist      
-: | :--------------------- | :------------------ | :------------------
 1 | 2017-01-01 10:00:00+00 | 2017-01-01 10:00:00 | 2017-01-01 12:00:00
 2 | 2017-01-01 09:00:00+00 | 2017-01-01 09:00:00 | 2017-01-01 11:00:00
 3 | 2017-01-01 15:00:00+00 | 2017-01-01 15:00:00 | 2017-01-01 17:00:00
 4 | 2017-01-01 08:00:00+00 | 2017-01-01 08:00:00 | 2017-01-01 10:00:00
```

You can check it at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=165d30280f18b2a9b136538819f4e8c9)*

---

References:

- PostgreSQL documentation about [`AT TIME ZONE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT)

---

<sup>1</sup> I don't know the MySQL equivalent. I hope you actually are using PostgreSQL, since your identifiers are `"double quoted"` and not `` `backtick quoted` `` as in MySQL.

Comment: you didnt understood my question. i said queries are already made in the format shown(see linked imaeg) .i want to somehow use the existing query to change time to IST . thanku for the effort though

Comment: Your original query *does what it does*. If you want to convert from one time zone to another, you need to do another thing: use `AT TIME ZONE 'IST'`.